# How do I create a Rust struct that can link to another instance of itself?

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm trying to create a chain of struct instances, like this:

```
Struct_instance_a:
id:1
prev:None

Struct_instance_b:
id:2
prev:Struct_instance_a

etc..
```

But getting this error from the compiler:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `a`
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `a`
  --> src/main.rs:31:9
   |
28 |         let a = crate::Node::new(None, 1);
   |             - move occurs because `a` has type `Node`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
29 |         let b=crate::Node::new(Some(a), 2);
   |                                     - value moved here
30 |
31 |         assert_eq!(a.id, b.prev.unwrap().id);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

This is my code snippet:

```
fn main() {
    println!("hello");
}

pub struct Node {
    prev: Option<Box<Node>>,
    id: u64,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(prev: Option<Node>, id:u64) -> Node {
        Node {
            prev: match prev {
                None => None,
                Some(prev) => Some(Box::new(prev))
            },
            id
        }
    }
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    #[test]
    fn test_children() {
        let a = crate::Node::new(None, 1);
        let b = crate::Node::new(Some(a), 2);

        assert_eq!(a.id, b.prev.unwrap().id);
    }

}
```

I'm new to Rust and trying to understand why this doesn't work. So far I've read about ownership and borrowing and lifetimes and tried a few combinations of those. It feels like I'm close to the solution but missing some fundamental piece of knowledge yet.

Comment: Related: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: Nit: your `match` could also be written as `prev.map(Box::new)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `Node::new(some(a), 2)`, then a is no longer accessible, it's ownership now belongs to `b`.

That's why, when you later do `a.id` it says `value borrowed here after move`, you moved the ownership to `b`, therefore you can't do `a.id`. The only way to access `a` is through `b.prev.unwrap()` (which is what you did.

If you want for the Node `a` to be accessible from both `a` and `b.prev` there's many ways to do that.

One of the ways involve not moving the value at all (so `b` never has ownership of `a` to begin with). This can be done with references:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("hello");
}

pub struct Node<'inner_node> {
    prev: Option<&'inner_node Node<'inner_node>>,
    id: u64,
}

impl<'inner_node> Node<'inner_node> {
    fn new<'a>(prev: Option<&'a Node<'a>>, id: u64) -> Node<'a> {
        Node {
            prev,
            id
        }
    }
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    #[test]
    fn test_children() {
        let a = crate::Node::new(None, 1);
        let b = crate::Node::new(Some(&a), 2);

        assert_eq!(a.id, b.prev.unwrap().id);
    }

}
```

This introduces lifetime annotations, which might not be what you want. In that case, you can use the `RC` struct, which is a smart pointer that allows a value to have multiple owners at the cost of some run-time checks:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    println!("hello");
}

pub struct Node {
    prev: Option<Rc<Node>>,
    id: u64,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(prev: Option<Rc<Node>>, id: u64) -> Node {
        Node {
            prev,
            id
        }
    }
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::rc::Rc;


    #[test]
    fn test_children() {
        let a = Rc::new(crate::Node::new(None, 1));
        let b = crate::Node::new(Some(a.clone()), 2);

        assert_eq!(a.id, b.prev.unwrap().id);
    }

}
```

Note that for this to work we are doing `a.clone()`. This clones the *RC pointer*, it doesn't clone the node. So now there exists 2 pointers (`a` and `b.prev`) but only 1 (excluding `b` itself) Node.

One of the disadvantages of RC is that now the value inside is immutable. If you need to mutate the nodes, they would have to be `Rc<RefCell<Node>>` instead of `Rc<Node>`.

`RefCell` is another smart pointer, just like `Rc`. Where `Rc` allows a value to have multiple owners, `RefCell` allows to obtain a mutable reference (via run-time checks) to the inner object even if the `RefCell` itself is not mutable. By combining `Rc` and `RefCell` you can have multiple owners that can mutate the value.

Comment: `RefCell` is not a smart pointer, it is a kind of [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/).

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I actually don't need to reference `a` directly once it's within `b`. Referencing just from `b` is enough. I updated my test to look like this and now it passes:

```
#[test]
    fn test_children() {
        let a = crate::Node::new(None, 1);
        let b = crate::Node::new(Some(a), 2);

        assert_eq!(1, b.prev.unwrap().id);
    }
```